# Biblatex publist style does not work on periodical type

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

When I pass `style=publist` as a `biblatex` option and put `\plauthorname[R. Daneel]{Olivaw}` on the preamble, a `@collection` entry is printed as follows:

> **2005** (with Hari Seldon), eds. *Foundations of Psychohistory*.

However, if the same entry were of type `@periodical`, it would print instead:

> **2005** (with Hari Seldon), eds. *Foundations of Psychohistory*. Ed. by Hari Seldon and R. Daneel Olivaw.

How can I do to have `@periodical` work the same as `@collection` under the `publist` style.

Comment: Please consider adding an example document that reproduces the problem. Your question is of course understandable without it, but it is much easier to get started investigating this if we don't have to build your setup from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `biblatex-publist` which I have just fixed for the next release (V. 1.18). I forgot to `\clearname{editor}` at two places.

Workaround:

```
\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
    \if@hlauthor
        \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \printnames{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
            }%
            \adddot\addspace%
            \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
            \clearname{editor}%
    \else% \if@hlauthor false
        \ifnameundef{editor}
            {}
            {%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:marginyear}%
             \usebibmacro{bpl:year+labelyear}%
             \addspace%
             \printnames{editor}%
             \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
             \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
             \clearname{editor}%
            }%
    \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}
```